# Where does Spring EL wiring value from

Tags: spring

All:

I wonder how to find where does a spEL value located?

Such as :

```
<property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:sybase:Tds:${brs.dsread}" />
```

I check all *.properties file in the eclipse project, but there is no definition. Other than those properties file, where else can I look for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not SpEL it's a simple Property Placeholder.

It could be anywhere on the classpath (e.g. in a jar).

Turn on DEBUG logging for org.springframework to figure out where it comes from.

Comment: Thanks for help. I am pretty new to Spring, could you tell me how to turn the logging on and track back the variable?

Comment: Put log4j on the classpath and set up a log4j.properties or log4j.xml file. Google log4j.